# AKAudioPlayernode.play crash

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, audiokit

I am having a strange crash within the AKAudioPlayer. It crashes when i setup, play 4 times, teardown, then setup again and the first play crashes.

It crashes with

```
AKAudioPlayer.swift:startTime:171:AKAudioPlayer.startTime = 0.0, startingFrame: 0
AKAudioPlayer.swift:updatePCMBuffer():564:read 21888 frames into buffer
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

with this implementation:

```
import Foundation
import AudioKit

@objc(MetronomeSoundProcessor)
class MetronomeSoundProcessor: NSObject {

  var player: AKAudioPlayer?

  func setup() -> NSError? {
    do {
      let file = try AKAudioFile(readFileName: "ClickDown.wav")
      player = try AKAudioPlayer(file: file)
      AudioKit.output = player
      try AudioKit.start()
      return nil
    } catch let error as NSError {
      return error
    }
  }

  @objc func play() {
    player?.play()
  }

  @objc func tearDown() {
    player?.disconnect()
    player = nil
  }
}
```

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?